# Add number of radio buttons selected (in php/js)

Tags: java, php, javascript

I have 5 sets of radio buttons, set1, set2, set3, set4, set5. Values are yes/no for each.

I need the number of yes's to be shown in a hidden text box.. ie 1,2,3,4 or 5, and obviously change as people select different options..

```
<input type="radio" name="set1" id="set1_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set1" id="set1_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set2" id="set2_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set2" id="set2_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set3" id="set3_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set3" id="set3_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set4" id="set4_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set4" id="set4_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set5" id="set5_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set5" id="set5_yes" value="yes">


<input type="hidden" name="number_of_yes" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are setting a hidden field (which doesn't need to be readonly, by the way, since it is...well...hidden) I would probably only update it `onsubmit` of the `<form>`. If you really need it updated as you go just use an `onclick` or `onchange` instead. However you trigger it, you can try something like this:

```
yourForm.onsubmit = setYesCount;

function setYesCount() {
  var count = 0;

  // could use yourForm.getElementsByTagName(),
  // but since the OP didn't provide surrounding HTML:
  var els = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].type === "radio" && els[i].checked && els[i].value === "yes")
      count++;
  }
  // add an id attribute to the hidden input
  // for the following to work
  document.getElementById("number_of_yes").value = count;
}
```

(And if I don't say it somebody else will: you could do this in one or two lines with jQuery.)

EDIT: jQuery version - again I've put it on the form's submit event (I'm assuming you have a form and can fill in the id). You can change this to a change or click event if needed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourFormsId").submit(function() {
         $('input[name="number_of_yes"]').val(
            $('input:checked[type="radio"][value="yes"]').length);
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Only thing is I have another set or radio buttons that have yes/no value.. I could change yes/no to yesX/noX which may overcome.. or should I link too these radio button sets?

Comment: Well (as you've noticed) my example jQuery code uses a selector that gets all of the radio buttons. If you need to keep separate totals for different groups you can refine the selector in several ways, including for example: (A) Select based on some containing element; (B) Use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector syntax and name the different groups appropriately; (C) Give each group its own class and select on that. jQuery's [selector doco](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) has plenty of options and examples.

Comment: (A) radio button set name? set1, set2, set3 etc?

Comment: In addition to having the above radio buttons I have another radio group:

Comment: <input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_3" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_4" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="group1_5" value="5">

Now this radio set is BEFORE the other radio buttons. So if the select radio option 3 in this radio button then only to check yes's of the first 3 radio sets.. set1, set2, set 3 etc, if they select1, then only check set1..

Hope that makes sense? Complex?

Comment: Sorry do the above changes address the radio buttons that also have yes, that do not need to be counted or set the number of sets, ie set1, set2, etc to be checked?

Comment: What I said in my original answer (including the edit for jQuery) applies only to the code you posted in your original question. What I said in my comment, mentioning the A, B, C suggestions, applies to your comment about having an extra requirement for another set of radio buttons, and was intended just to give you some ideas to get you started (given that the new requirement was pretty vague). I think you have enough to go on: maybe if you read through the jQuery selector doco I linked to in that comment you'll be able to figure it out. (If I do it _all_ for you I will have to bill you...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to maintain a counter variable whenever NO or YES is clicked. Define a class for all NO and YES buttons

I'd imagine doing something like this

```
var ctr = 0;
$(document).ready( function($) {
     $(".noradio").click((function () {
                 if (ctr != 0)
                 {
                     ctr--;
                 }
           })
     $(".yesradio").click()(function () {
                     ctr++;
           })
     $('input[name=hiddeninputname]').val(ctr);
});
```

Comment: You want `.click(function() ...` rather than `.click()(function() ...`. And your "yes" click handler is decrementing when it should be incrementing, though I think you're better off recalculating the total each time rather than trying to keep a running total: less likely to have weird bugs (especially when your ctr variable is global) and also works in cases where the values are set programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Fixed code as suggested. Does naming variable something more unique solve the problem? Just wanted to put the point across that OP has to do something like this...